# Switching limit and integral: example $f_n(x)=e^{-nx}/\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Consider following theorem:

> If $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of continuous functions $[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$, then $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a ^b f_n = \int_a ^b \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n.$$

Now my notes want to illustrate that there are cases where limit and integral can be switched, without having uniformly convergent $f_n$'s:

Let $f_n(x) = e^{-nx}/\sqrt{x},\,\, n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Is it clear that $\lim_n f_n(x)=0, \forall x\in ]0,1]$ and therefore the integral of the limit function is $0$. Then my notes say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f_n = 0$ $\,\, (A)$. This example shows that we can switch limit and integral here, but $f_n$ is only continuous (and defined) on $]0,1]$ and does not converge uniformly $(B)$.

---

My questions:

$(A)$: I can't prove this equality. I've tried using Taylor approximations but the result does not vanish for $n\to\infty$. How can I show this result?

$(B)$: How can I show that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly? I feel like it has something to do with the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}f_n(x) = +\infty$ for all $n$, but I can't write it done properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's the standard proof in Rudin. Does that not satisfy you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A): Make the change of variable $y=nx$. You gte $\int_0^{1}e^{-nx} /\sqrt x dx=\frac 1 {\sqrt n} \int_0^{n} e^{-y} /\sqrt y dy \leq \frac 1 {\sqrt n} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-y} /\sqrt y dy$. Can you show that the last integral is finite?

(B) $\sup_{\{0\leq x\leq 1\}}  e^{-nx} /\sqrt x \geq e^{-1}\sqrt n$ as seen by taking $x=\frac 1 n$. Hence the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thank you so much! As for (A): the last integral is $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$.